# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jmetal'

Tags: python, optimization, error-handling, module

I wanted to use jmetalpy for multi-objective optimization. I installed the tool using the following code in anaconda prompt.

```
pip install jmetalpy
```

After installing I tried the run the code below:

```
from jmetal.algorithm.multiobjective import NSGAII
from jmetal.operator import SBXCrossover, PolynomialMutation
from jmetal.problem import ZDT1
from jmetal.util.termination_criterion import StoppingByEvaluations

problem = ZDT1()

algorithm = NSGAII(
    problem=problem,
    population_size=100,
    offspring_population_size=100,
    mutation=PolynomialMutation(probability=1.0 / problem.number_of_variables, distribution_index=20),
    crossover=SBXCrossover(probability=1.0, distribution_index=20),
    termination_criterion=StoppingByEvaluations(max_evaluations=25000)
)

algorithm.run()
```

Error received:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jmetal'
```

The error comes from the first statement itself

What I tried?

```
import jmetal
```

Throws the same error

```
import jmetalpy
```

Throws similar error.

Python version- 3.8
Windows 64-bit version

Comment: are you using the same interpreter?
Try running in console: `python` `import jmetal`

Comment: Yes. tried that. didn't work either

Comment: in that case, first try `python -m pip install jmetal`, then retry the above again

Comment: Throw this error: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement jmetal
ERROR: No matching distribution found for jmetal

Comment: what python version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible issues:

1. You are using a different environment, probably installed it on base and now using a new set up one
2. There was some error during installation (less likely, since you must of seen it).

Solution:

Pycharm:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html

VSCode:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Jupyter:

Before starting type:

```
conda activate (your_environment)
jupyter-notebook
```

Comment: anaconda doesn't have anything to do with jupyter notebooks, you can have one without the other

Comment: "I wanted to use jmetalpy for multi-objective optimization. I installed the tool using the following code in anaconda prompt."
Read before commenting @Mahrkeenerh, obviously the solution is specifically for his case.

Comment: stackoverflow is not just for a specific case. In some cases, there's no way to provide a general solution, but if possible, it's better to generalize it, so when anyone else with a similar problem is looking for a solution, they find it.